# Update row based on id

Tags: php

i need to to change the value of an element of an array

```
 $_SESSION['developersArray'] = array(
                0 => array(
                    'id' => 0, // This is the row id
                    'name' => 'a',
                    'gender' => 'b',
                    
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'c',
                    'gender' => 'd',
                    
                ),
                2 => array(
                    'id' => 2,
                    'name' => 'e',
                    'gender' => 'f',
                    
                ));
```

I NEED: update the array SET name='XXXX' WHERE id=2

i tried the following with no luck:

```
$input['id']='2'; 
foreach ($_SESSION['developersArray'] as $developer) {
        if ($developer['id'] == $input['id']) { 
                $_SESSION['developersArray']['name'] = 'xxxx';}}
```

I have tried all kinds of foreach, while, implode methods pieced together from other posts but none of them deal with this specific problem. Any help would be appreciated. THanks

Comment: Can you share your approaches in code?

Comment: $input['id']='2'; 
foreach ($_SESSION['developersArray'] as $developer) {
        if ($developer['id'] == $input['id']) { 
                $_SESSION['developersArray']['name'] = 'xxxx';}}

Comment: It should be `$_SESSION['developersArray'][$developer]['name'] = 'xxxx';` ...

Comment: so `$_SESSION['developersArray']['name']` how will this know which array key like 1 or 2 and so on to access in the nested array you have? And when you have a given key why not get to the array directly? You already have `$input['id']`, why not use `$_SESSION['developersArray'][$input['id']]['name']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you need to set the *name* attribute one level deeper in the array.

For example:

```
$input['id'] = 2;
foreach ($_SESSION['developersArray'] as $index => $developer) {
    if ($developer['id'] === $input['id']) {
        $_SESSION['developersArray'][$index]['name'] = 'XXXX';
    }
}
```

Or with a "fancy" one liner, you can do this (with PHP 7.4 or above):

```
array_walk($_SESSION['developersArray'], fn(array &$developer) => $developer['id'] === $input['id'] ? $developer['name'] = 'XXXX' : null);
```

If the *array index* and the *id* are the same, then you can use like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['developersArray'] as $index => $developer) {
    if ($index === $input['id']) {
        $_SESSION['developersArray'][$index]['name'] = 'XXXX';
    }
}
```

In general it is a good practice to use strict type as you can. So as your array stores *id* as an *integer*, you should compare with another *integer* with the `===` check. If your `$input['id']` comes from the user, and it is a string, you can simply cast it like this: `(int) $input['id']`

Comment: If the array index and the id are the same, how to use it inside "fancy" one liner? @MárkMatuz

Comment: array_walk callback function may have a second parameter, the key. So you can do like this: array_walk($_SESSION['developersArray'], fn(array &$developer, $index) => $index === $input['id'] ? $developer['name'] = 'XXXX' : null);